# Running jekyll server in windows 7 results in "error: Invalid argument"

Tags: ruby, jekyll

It is my first time using Jekyll. Running `jekyll server` gives me this error:

```
Configuration file: h:/jekyll_demo/myblog/_config.yml
            Source: h:/jekyll_demo/myblog
       Destination: h:/jekyll_demo.myblog/_site
      Generating... error: Invalid argument - h:/jekyll_demo/myblog/_site/h:. use --trace to view backtrace
```

ruby is 1.9.3p545
jekyll is 1.4.3
pygments.rb is 0.5.0

When run jekyll server --trace, it shows this message:

```
C:\Users\Administrator> jekyll server --trace
Configuration file: none
Source: C:/Users/Administrator
Destination: C:/Users/Administrator/_site 
Generating... 
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/ site.rb:145:in open': Permission denied - . (Errno::EACCES)         
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb :145:in entries'
```

Comment: What do you get when you follow the recommendation (run `jekyll server --trace` ?)

Comment: Also, please post your `_config.yml`.

Comment: when run jekyll server --trace,it show message as below:

Comment: when run jekyll server --trace,show the message as below {C:\Users\Administrator>jekyll server --trace
[33mConfiguration file: none[0m
            Source: C:/Users/Administrator
       Destination: C:/Users/Administrator/_site
      Generating... C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/
site.rb:145:in `open': Permission denied - . (Errno::EACCES)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:145:in `entries'}  @Bob Gilmore

Comment: add there is the _config.yml:name: 
"Your New Jekyll Site
markdown: redcarpet
pygments: true"

@ David Underwood

Comment: The original error message was using files in `h:/jekyll_demo/myblog`, but then when you ran it with --trace (which I moved into the problem statement; please add stack traces etc. into the problem statement, rather than as comments), you're showing that you ran it from `C:\Users\Administrator`.  Because of that, a lot of things changed, such as your config file changing from `h:/jekyll_demo/myblog/_config.yml` to `none`.  You need to do these things *consistently* if we're to have any chance of helping diagnose the problem.

Comment: sorry about that, I try in h:/jekyll_demo/myblog,and the error is that:   /h/jekyll_demo/myblog>jekyll server --trace
Configuration file: h:/jekyll_demo/myblog/_config.yml
 Source: h:/jekyll_demo/myblog
 Destination: h:/jekyll_demo/myblog/_site
 Generating... C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in 'mkdir':Incalid argument - h:/jekyll_demo/myblog/_site/h:(Errno::EINVAL)
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in 'fu_mkdir'
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'

Comment: yes that is the issue, now it had solved,thanks all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Jekyll 1.4.3 is broken on Windows, this is a known issue.

[v1.4.3 is broken on Windows #1948](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1948)

What you can do is to install Jekyll 1.4.2 instead of using the latest one. Or use Linux/Mac, because Jekyll doesn't support Windows officially.

`gem install jekyll --version "=1.4.2"`